# Modify Cart Item Selection Quantity

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, bundle, selection

I'm looking to change the quantity of selections of a particular bundle in the cart from a dropdown on the Cart page. The issue I'm having is getting the labels of the selections to update. You can see in the screenshot I've included the quantity selection is 200 (and the selection quantities have changed correctly, along with pricing), however the option text on the product has not. Is there an easy way to do this inside of an Observer method?

[image: Bundle Selections Quantity]

Comment: I don't understand the question. What have not changed? Beside of this if you are working with so high quantities, you may not use dropdowns? Or do you limit the amount of entries to 10,30,50,100,200 or something? Just my 2cents :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I discovered the issue I was experiencing with this, which is Magento saves the quantity for the selections in the database, I don't remember what table they come from but they are stored there. In my research I couldn't find any way to modify the quantities in that table as I could not find corresponding models. The issue I was experiencing was updating the quantity of the selections for a bundle in the cart and having them reflect in the cart - without removing/readding the bundle.